# Shouldn't the same post posted twice be deleted?

Tags: support

The OP had posted a question to both Security.SE and Superuser. The post in Security.SE was migrated to Superuser and it has answers. The original post he posted here has been closed as a duplicate of the migrated post.

https://superuser.com/questions/643847/whats-wrong-with-my-local-network (closed as a dupe)

[What's wrong with my local network and router?](https://superuser.com/questions/644102/whats-wrong-with-my-local-network-and-router) (the one with a answer)

Shouldn't [the question he originally posted](https://superuser.com/questions/643847/whats-wrong-with-my-local-network) here be deleted  ? It is a replica of the one which has answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they usually should be deleted. You can just flag the dupe and let us know :)

Comment: I did flag ! http://i.imgur.com/MX81FUG.png

Comment: @Gowtham: Huh. No idea what was going no there. Maybe I'm missing something.